# ¿Hay alguna forma de saber que paquetes y funciones han sido importados en un script de python?

Tags: python, importación, packages

Por curiosidad me pregunto si se puede generar algo así como un archivo `requirement.txt` automático partiendo de un script

Comment: ejecuta el comando `pip freeze > requirements.txt` con cualquier módulo de ejecución de procesos como `subprocess` o `os`

Comment: Si solo quieres los nombres de los módulos importados, `sys.modules.keys()`. Para obtener más detalles puede ser útil este paquete https://docs.python.org/3/library/modulefinder.html

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar dir() para hacerlo, ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import os

modules = dir()

print(modules)
```

Salida:

```
['KITE', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__spec__', 'np', 'os', 'sys']
```

Comment: Dir (si no le pasas argumentos) lista todas las variables en el ambito actual (en este caso del ambito global), entre ellos los modulos. Te diría que ofrescas una forma de obtener solamente los modulos importados a partir de dir.